# Linq to Entities (EF 4.0) and group 2 unrelated tables into an aggregated object

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables (Document and Message) that have no foreign key relation, but the table Message have the id column from Document as a column (bad design, I know..)

Table Document:
DocId,
Name

Table Message:
MessageId,
DocId,
Value

One document object can have zero or more Message objects

I want to write a query that returns a list of an aggregated object called DocumentWithMessages:

```
public class DocumentWithMessages
{
Document Document {get;set;}
List<Message> Messages {get;set;}
}
```

The query should return all Documents (with or without a list of Messages)

I started to write such a method but it gives me an exception:

```
public ICollection<DocumentWithDocumentSplitMessages> GetSplitJobsWithMessages()
        {
            var messages = (from dm in ObjectContext.DocumentSplitMessages select dm).ToList();
            var jobs = from d in ObjectContext.Documents                       

                       let msgs = messages.Where(dm => dm.DocID == d.DocID).ToList()

                       select new DocumentWithDocumentSplitMessages()
                           {
                               Document = d,
                               DocumentSplitMessages = msgs
                           };                                    

            return jobs.ToList();
        }
```

The exception is:

System.NotSupportedException : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BraArkivDataModel.DocumentSplitMessage] ToList[DocumentSplitMessage](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BraArkivDataModel.DocumentSplitMessage])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How do I write such a query?

Comment: If you can change the code, why can't you change the EF model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use an approach similar to what you tried but using the *IQueryable* on the let clause:

```
var jobs = from d in ObjectContext.Documents                       

           let msgs = ObjectContext.DocumentSplitMessages.Where(dm => dm.DocID == d.DocID)

           select new DocumentWithDocumentSplitMessages()
           {
               Document = d,
               DocumentSplitMessages = msgs
           };                                    

        return jobs.ToList();
```

Comment: Didn't work for me I'm afraid. Still getting the same exception. Could it be due to the reason that I'm using the IObjectSet interface instead of the ObjectSet class? (Documents and DocumentSplitMessages are IObjectSets)

Comment: I got the solution. The DocumentSplitMessages list in the DocumentWithDocumentSplitMessages class has to be IEnumerable<DocumentSplitMessages>. I had that as a List<The DocumentSplitMessages> to begin with.